# Update one column as sum of other two columns

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

*I need to update each row of a table with one column as sum of other two columns in the same table*

**Something like this**

> UPDATE table1 SET table1.column1 = sum (table1.column1 +
>   table1.column2) for every row

**I have tried**

`This is working for me`

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 =(SELECT  SUM(column1 + column2)  FROM table1 where rowid = 1) WHERE rowid = 1
```

So I can do this by iterating each rowid by first selecting all rowId

```
for( all rowid as i){
    UPDATE table1 SET column1 =(SELECT  SUM(column1 + column2)  FROM table1 where rowid = i) WHERE rowid = i
    }
```

**But I need to do for all the rows in that table in one query**

*When I tried:*

```
update table1  set column1  = (select (column1  + column2) from table1 )
```

*this will summ all the values of column1 and column2
i want to do wrt to a row*

Any idea?

Me working in **sqLite** for Android

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's no need for loops or inner selects. Just try this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = column1 + column2
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. What method have you used? With rawQuery it doesn't work. With execSQL it works (for me), but documentation says: "Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE."

Comment: How to do the same using ContentValues? Instead of SQL

Answer (score 3):

It's allowed to read from columns in the `set` clause:

```
UPDATE  table1 
SET     column1 = column1 + column2
WHERE   rowid = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

For all the rows you need not `WHERE` predicate:

```
UPDATE table SET
  column1 = column1+column2
```

thats all.

Answer (score 0):

I found a cte worked best for me

```
;with new_count
as
(select rownumber
    ,sum(isnull([col1],0) + 
    isnull([col2],0) + 
    isnull([col3],0) + 
    isnull([col4],0) + 
    isnull([col5],0)) as [New Count]
    from #tbl1
    group by rownumber
)
update t1
    set t1.[New Count] = isnull(nc.[New Count],0)
    from new_count nc
    join #tbl1 t1
    on t1.rownumber = nc.rownumber
```

Comment: Could you explain what this solution is doing? It will be helpful for other people who are reading it.