# Possible to use ContentValues.put to update one column as sum of others

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Is it possible to use `ContentValues.put()` to update a column in a `SQLiteDatabse` to be the sum of other columns?

I have searched on here and on the web and the closest answer I have found is: [Update one column as sum of other two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213772/update-one-column-as-sum-of-other-two-columns). This doesn't quite answer my question because it requires a raw database command, which I would prefer to avoid (if possible).

I have a fairly static database that I have generated unique permutations in (long setup, fast queries). I am attempting to set a total column at the end for even faster sorting on the permutations. I am currently attempting to use:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(totalVal, sumString);
```

where I have tried to set `sumString` to both:

```
=val_1+val_2+val_3...
```

and

```
val_1+val_2+val3...
```

When I look at my database in adb shell, sqlite3 I see:

[image: totalVal sqlite dump]

Which looks... correct? Except when I query my database after this has been set, I get this in the log:

[image: totalVal from log]

My `val_*` columns show values in the same adb shell, sqlite3 dump. Also, I do not set the `totalVal` column to this `sumString` until the `val_*` columns are all populated with their values.

Is it just not possible to use `ContentValues.put()`? Does it do some sort of internal escaping?

The reason it seems like it should work to me is the `totalVal` column is set to `REAL` so if `ContentValues.put()` does do internal escaping I thought I would get an error since I would essentially be putting a `String` value in a column that should only accept `REAL`.

Like I said earlier, my database is pretty static and only there for fast queries and sorting. It would be possible for me to loop through all the `val_*` columns and manually sum them up. Although, there are thousands of rows in my database so I was hoping to avoid this and was looking for a more elegant way to do this.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLiteDatabase.update()` is just a convenience method for updating rows in the database, so in your case you are just overcomplicating things trying to use `ContentValues` instead of `SQLiteStatement` and binding arguments which is what `SQLiteDatabase.update()` uses internally but preventing that column names were considered Strings.

It's not very clear from your example but if you are trying to update some values and at the same time calculate the `totalVal` do something like this

```
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("UPDATE mytable SET val_1=?, val_2=?, val_3=?, totalVal=val_1+val_2+val_3 WHERE expr");
stmt.bindLong(1, 1);
stmt.bindLong(2, 3);
stmt.bindLong(3, 5);
stmt.executeUpdateDelete();
```

#### EDIT

So as mentioned in your comment you don't need to bind values, it's even simpler

```
 final int rows = db.compileStatement("UPDATE mytable SET totalVal=val_1+val_2+val_3").executeUpdateDelete();
```

and regarding your comment about *"raw"* SQL, `ContentValues` are not an option so this is the only way (AFAIK).

Comment: I am just trying to do an `UPDATE myTable SET totalVal=val_1+val_2+val_3`. All of the `val_*` columns have already been set and are static, so I don't need to bind values, I just need to update the `totalVal` column. Since both `SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement` and `SQLiteDatabase.execSQL` require "raw" SQL strings, is there an advantage to using `compileStatement` or would I only use that if binding were required?