# SQL calculation X + Y = Z

Tags: sql

New to SQL and I'm sorry if this question has already been asked. I'm looking to create a table with 3 columns X, Y, and Z where I will add the X and Y values to the table. Then I'd like to create a stored procedure that will take the row values of X and Y, add them together, and store that value as Z in my table. I'd like to be able to add X and Y values whenever I want and then run the stored procedure after to calculate Z.

```
CREATE TABLE XYZ 
(
    X INT NOT NULL,
    Y INT NOT NULL,
    Z INT NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO XYZ (X, Y) VALUES (3, 5);
INSERT INTO XYZ (X, Y) VALUES (5, 8);
INSERT INTO XYZ (X, Y) VALUES (8, 13);

CREATE PROCEDURE CalculateZ
AS
    SELECT X, Y, Z = X + Y
    INTO XYZ
    FROM XYZ;
GO

EXECUTE CalculateZ;
GO

INSERT INTO XYZ (X, Y) VALUES (13, 21);

EXECUTE CalculateZ;
GO
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update one column as sum of other two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213772/update-one-column-as-sum-of-other-two-columns)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do that.  Instead, create `z` as a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE XYZ (
    X INT NOT NULL,
    Y INT NOT NULL,
    Z AS (X + Y)
);
```

`Z` is then calculated automatically (either when data in the row changes or when queried).  There no need to update the table.  No need for a stored procedure either.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your stored procedure.  You want an `UPDATE` to the original table, not an `INSERT`.

```
update XYZ
set z = x + y
```